# API pagination, how to implement page token paging method?

Tags: php, rest, pagination

I am working on implementing an API interface for my project.

As i know, there are different forms to make pagination through the results, like the following:

```
https://example.com/api/purchaseorders?page=2&pagesize=25
```

But, i see many APIs like google use a different approach, in which they use a "pageToken" to let the user move between the pages of results, for example:

```
https://example.com/api/purchaseorders?pagesize=25&pageToken=ClkKHgoRc291cmNlX2NyZWF0ZWRfYXQSCQjA67Si5sr
```

So instead of `page=2` they used `pageToken=[token]`.

It is not clear for me the idea of pageToken and how to implement it.

It will be helpful if you guide me to any resources so i can get more knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you, i know it is too broad, but really i don't know from where to start. What the benefit of using page token over offset method?

Comment: No idea, maybe it's used to cache requests or prevent people from scripting arbitrary requests to extract all data. The idea being that you only get the next page token if you got the current page and haven't been rate limited yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple standalone example using the filesystem as a keyvalue store (since a filesystem will always be available).

```
$requestParameters = [];
if (($token = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"pageToken")) && is_readable("/tmp/$token")) {
   $requestParameters = file_get_contents("/tmp/$token");
} else {   
    $requestParameters = [
       "q" => filter_input(INPUT_GET,"q"),
       "pageSize" => filter_input(INPUT_GET,"pageSize",FILTER_VALIDATE_INT),
       "page" => filter_input(INPUT_GET,"page",FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)
   ];
}

$nextPageRequestParameters = $requestParameters;
$nextPageRequestParameters["page"]++;

$nextPageToken = md5(serialize($nextPageRequestParameters)); //This is not ideal but at least people can't guess it easily. 


file_put_contents("/tmp/$nextPageToken", serialize($nextPageRequestParameters));

//Do request using $requestParameters 
$result = [ "nextPageToken" => $nextPageToken, "data" => $resultData ];
echo json_encode($result);
```